# Call a Qt project from another Qt project

Tags: qt, project

I have a project which monitors the network. And another project which does some other operation.

Now I want a button in project one which, when I click it, should run project 2.
Is it possible?

Comment: Try [QProcess](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html)

Comment: in that case (two Qt apps), you could also use shared memory (QSharedmemory) to communicate between the two apps

Answer (score 1):

Does it just need to be started, or do you also require communication between them?

In any case, [QProcess](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html) might fit your bill since you're using Qt anyway. You can use it to launch your process and it allows you to [communicate via channels](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#communicating-via-channels).

Alternatively, if you require some other form of interprocess communication, [Qt provides several options](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8-snapshot/ipc.html) , one of which is QtDBus as suggested by Neox.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Barts answer if you want to establish an interprocess communication between two executables in your projects you might want to take a look at [`QtDbus`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtdbus.html) module. Note however that this is only available under Linux platforms.